# Using non-negative continuous variable to constrain binary variable

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem. I am programming a mixed integer linear model. $S_{ij}$ $\in$ {$0$,$1$}. And $o_{ij}$ is a non-negative continuous variable. $o_{ij}$ lower bound is zero. where $i$ and $j$ $=1,2,3,...,N$. 
I want to constrain $S_{ij}$ $=0$ when $o_{ij}$ $\le0$. And when $o_{ij}$ $\ge1$,$S_{ij}$ $=1$.

If $o_{ij}$ $\ge1$ then $S_{ij}$ $=1$.

If $o_{ij}$ $\le0$ then $S_{ij}$ $=0$.

I have two constraint

$M*S_{ij}\ge o_{ij}$   $\forall i,j=1,2,3,...,N$

where $M$ is a large positive constant.

$o_{ij} \ge S_{ij}$  $\forall i,j=1,2,3,...,N$

But it doesn't work. I  program in python with gurobi. Solution result show all $S_{ij}$ $=1$ and $o_{ij}=$ M (a large positive constant). Sorry, my English is not good. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: The solution satisfies "$S_{ij}$ $=0$ when $o_{ij}$ $=0$. And when $o_{ij}$ $\ge1$,$S_{ij}$ $=1$", does it not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. I want to constrain $S_{ij}$ (binary variable) by $o_{ij}$ (non-negative continuous variable). But my constraint doesn't work.

Comment: it seems to work just fine: the solution satisfies your constraint